# HTML5 video 'ended' event not firing in Chrome 22.0+

Tags: google-chrome, video

I looked around on this topic, but couldn't find anything resent. My tests show that the latest version of Google Chrome (22+) on Mac and PC have a broken vide `ended` event.

I created a sample page here with an HTML5 video and a event listener for `ended` both using jQuery and regular addEventListener to call an alert on video end. It gets called correctly in Safari and Firefox but not Chrome:

http://sadbot.com/videotest.html

If anyone has any idea why it doesn't work or if I'm doing something wrong please let me know. Note that I have live production code setup similar to this that has been working for months and seems to have broken with Chrome's latest rollout.

Comment: use show controls and scroll to the end event firing

Comment: Interesting observation Arun, video end event does indeed fire if you enable controls and fast forward to the end, otherwise it's still broken. Doesn't fix the issue but does give us a better understanding.

Comment: for a 11 sec video showing only 10 sec..but on the 11th sec firing happens ??

Comment: i tnk this has something to do with video meta data.

Comment: Good finds Arun, I have now reported this as a Chromium bug here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044122/html5-video-ended-event-not-firing-in-chrome-22-0#comment17711579_13044122

Comment: Sorry that link would be: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157543

Comment: Works as of Chrome 28 (probably fixed quite a few versions ago).

Answer (score 4):

If looping is enabled, the ended event does not fire.

Comment: Good point, but you can see in the example that the video is not looping.

Comment: If looping is enabled you get a 'seeking' event and when you get it the player's currentTime property is 0, so you could look for that and call it an 'ended' event.

Comment: @mhenry1384 nice workaround, thanks

Answer (score 0):

An an FYI, the issue has been verified as a bug in the [Chromium tracker](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157543). I ended up "fixing" the issue by specifying .ogv file in the video source first instead of after the h.264 file. Apparently Chrome now support .ogv just fine without the same issue.